# Jenkins + HockeyKit

Tags: android, ios, continuous-integration, jenkins, ota

I'm developing iOS/Android apps. And I want to use Jenkins + HockeyKit to deploy my applications. I want to host HockeyKit on my server. Is this good idea? Can you tell more open source alternatives to HockeyKit?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is TestFlight:
https://testflightapp.com/

They offer a hosted solution, so it's not being hosted on your own server, however they provide a lot of features.

There is also a plugin for Jenkins that allows you to publish your builds to TestFlight:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Testflight+Plugin

Also HockeyApp:
http://hockeyapp.net/
They provide a hosted solution using HockeyKit

Comment: Just an additional note: HockeyApp is not using HockeyKit on the server side, instead providing many many more features including crash reporting for multiple platforms too. But is API compatible with the SDK of HockeyKit. And there is also a Jenkins plugin available for HockeyApp.

Comment: I want to use my server for deploy

Comment: @Slav Deprecated: This plugin has been removed from the Jenkins Update Centre
The testflightapp service no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an open source alternative to HockeyKit, check out [Knappsack](http://knappsack.com).

There is also a hosted solution with a free tier that might work for you. Here is a link to the source on GitHub: [Knappsack Source](https://github.com/sparcedge/knappsack)

Currently, there isn't any way to integrate Knappsack with your build server, so a custom solution is needed there.

Comment: [UPDATE] knappsack does not exist anymore